# having difficulty with SQL in vb.net program

Tags: vb.net

```
    Private Sub btnAddRecord_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddRecord.Click

    Dim arrImage() As Byte
    Dim strImage As String
    Dim myMs As New IO.MemoryStream
    '
    If Not IsNothing(Me.PictureBox2.Image) Then
        Me.PictureBox2.Image.Save(myMs, Me.PictureBox2.Image.RawFormat)
        arrImage = myMs.GetBuffer
        strImage = "?"
    Else
        arrImage = Nothing
        strImage = "NULL"
    End If
    Dim Conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OleDB.12.0; Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Student_Records.accdb")
    Conn.Open()
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    cmd.Connection = Conn
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Student_Information(Surname, First, Last, Department,Session, [Mat_Num], Picture) VALUES(" & Me.txtSurname.Text & ",'" & Me.txtFirst.Text & ",'" & Me.txtLast.Text & ",'" & Me.txtDeaprtment.Text & ",'" & Me.txtSession.Text & ",'" & Me.txtMat_Num.Text & "'," & strImage & ")"

    If strImage = "?" Then
        cmd.Parameters.Add(strImage, OleDb.OleDbType.Binary).Value = arrImage
    End If
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Conn.Close()
```

End Sub

> syntax error in INSERT INTO statement always displays.

please what is wrong?

Comment: Take the CommandText value and test it, I bet you are not closing all that quotes

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems in your query.

The first one is easy to fix. The words FIRST, SESSION and LAST are reserved keywords in Access and if you want to use them for your columns then you should enclose them in square brakets

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Student_Information" & _ 
  "(Surname, [First], [Last], Department, [Session], ....."
```

The second problem is more complex and more serious. When you want to build a sql command do not use string concatenation to build the command. NEVER.

This is [considered the GOTO of sql programming](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) because is the origin of numerous problems as Sql Injection (a bit harder to execute on Access but still ...) and parsing problems. Like the one that you have here because you have forgotten to use quotes around the text values.

The only solution is to use always a parameterized query

```
Dim cmdText= "INSERT INTO Student_Information" & _ 
"(Surname, [First], [Last], Department,[Session], [Mat_Num], Picture) " & _ 
"VALUES(@surname, @first, @last, @dep, @ses, @mat, @pic"

Using Conn = New OleDbConnection("...."
Using Cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, Conn)

   Conn.Open()
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@surname", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = Me.txtSurname.Text
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@first", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = Me.txtFirst.Text
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@last", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = Me.txtLast.Text
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@dep", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = Me.txtDeaprtment.Text 
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@ses", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = Me.txtSession.Text
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@mat", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = Me.txtMat_Num.Text 
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@pic", OleDb.OleDbType.Binary).Value = arrImage
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

End Using
End Using
```

Notice also that every disposable object like the connection and the command should be enclosed in a Using statement to be properly closed and destroyed when they are no more needed

Comment: the code has been modified but  same error still displays

Comment: Please check  that you have added all the parameters required with the proper name,type and order. I have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

you are missing quotes for each value, in any case it is better to use parameters:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Student_Information(Surname, First, Last, Department,Session, [Mat_Num], Picture) VALUES(@param1,@param2,@param3,@param4,@param5,param6,@param7)"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1",  Me.txtSurname.Text)
...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param7",  strImage)
```